# SQL: Pivot from Long to Wide Format and Get Sums

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, transpose

In SQL (AGINITY, Amazon Redshift), I want to group by columns COL1, COL2, and COL3.

Then I want to transpose COL5 so that it will get the sum from COL4.

I think this has to do with converting from long format to wide format. I know how to do it in R but not in SQL. The values are not just A and B by the way. There are about 10 other ones because this is just a subset of many more rows.

I have a dataset as follows:

```
  COL1   COL2       COL3   COL4    COL5
 alpha   beta      gamma     15       A
 alpha   beta      gamma     20       A
 alpha   beta    epsilon     30       A
 zeta    beta      gamma     18       B
 zeta   delta      gamma     13       B
```

I want to change it to:

```
  COL1   COL2       COL3      A     B     C    D  .... 
 alpha   beta      gamma     35     0   ...  ...  ....
 alpha   beta    epsilon     30     0   ...  ...  ....
 zeta    beta      gamma      0    18   ...  ...  ....
 zeta   delta      gamma      0    13   ...  ...  ....
```

Thanks!

Comment: are there only A,B in col5 or do you have many more values?

Comment: There are more values

Comment: you should mention that in the question and show the expected output as well.

Comment: just edited the question, also this is different I think because there is a group by involved

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate. Anyway, you can do this - just replace the table name: select col1, col2, col3, ISNULL([A], 0) as [A], ISNULL([B], 0) AS [B]
from
(
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from @tmp
)src
pivot
(
sum(col4)
for col5 in ([A],[B])
)pvt

Comment: If it's just 10 static columns, just hard code them, right? If it's a dynamic list, then you can dynamically build the query. I think @vkp probably assumed it was a dynamic list, and that's why he closed this as a duplicate, but that doesn't seem entirely clear.

Comment: @maxszczurek you're right. It is a dynamic query because when I run this it will not always be 10 values in that column. It could be 50. So I cannot hard code the 10

Comment: I am using Aginity to run these queries and it looks like pivot is not an option. That is why I am having trouble with this. It is recommended to use the functions: DECODE and/or SYSTEM VIEWS. Still figuring it out.